# My character is not switching right or left like subway surfer in 2D?

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, movement

I am making a 2D subway surfer type of game right now and I found this code on the internet that switches the lane of the player but the problem is it doesn't switch. When I play the scene it won't move it will just give the of "int" desiredLane. Why is this happening?

---

**CODE**

```
private const float LANE_DISTANCE = 3.0f;

[Header("Movement")]
public float moveSpeed;

public int desiredLane = 1; //0 = Left 1 = Middle 2 = Right
```

---

```
void MobileSwipeControl()
{
    //Movement Input
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        MoveLane(false);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        MoveLane(true);

    //Calculate where we should be in the future
    Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position.y * Vector3.up;

    if (desiredLane == 0)
        targetPosition += Vector3.left * LANE_DISTANCE; 
    else if (desiredLane == 2)
        targetPosition += Vector3.right * LANE_DISTANCE;

    //Let's calculate our move delta
    Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;
    moveVector.x = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized.x * moveSpeed;
    moveVector.y = moveSpeed;

    //Move the player
    myBody.velocity = Vector2.up * moveSpeed;
 }
```

---

```
private void MoveLane(bool goingRight)
{
    desiredLane += (goingRight) ? 1 : -1;
    desiredLane = Mathf.Clamp(desiredLane, 0, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found out the answer thanks to Zibelas! I forgot to apply moveVector to my movement.

---

```
//Move the player
myBody.velocity = moveVector * moveSpeed;
```

---

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as Accepted, if your problem has been fixed.